# Selenium web driver not able to locate an element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I'm using Selenium webdriver to click on a textbox which is identified by this as id  `objdbColumnVO[6].columnValue`. While replaying , selenium is not able to locate this element on the webpage.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="objdbColumnVO[6].columnValue" onkeydown="return noenter(event);" id="objdbColumnVO[6].columnValue" class="form-control" value="" title="" aria-invalid="false">
```

I have tried all the below options but no luck.

```
//var textbox=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id("objdbColumnVO[6].columnValue"));

WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id("objdbColumnVO[6].columnValue")).click();

//var EnterPolicy = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.name("objdbColumnVO[6].columnValue"));

//EnterPolicy.click();

//WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.className("col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-5  caselog-custom-text")).click();

var element = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.className("col-md-6.col-lg-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-5.caselog-custom-text"));
element.click();
```

Comment: Can you please add the element's html source as well?

Comment: <input type="text" name="objdbColumnVO[6].columnValue" onkeydown="return noenter(event);" id="objdbColumnVO[6].columnValue" class="form-control" value="" title="" aria-invalid="false">

Comment: By.cssSelector("input[class='form-control']") maybe try this,

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *xpath*:

  ```
  WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control' and contains(@onkeydown, 'noenter')][starts-with(@name, 'objdbColumnVO') and contains(@id, '6')]")).click();
  ```
- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.cssSelector("input.form-control[onkeydown*='noenter'][name^='objdbColumnVO'][id*='6']")).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this if it works

```
WebElement element =driver.findElement(By.name("objdbColumnVO[6].columnValue"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```